# Set a window transparent

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been trying to set **BlueStacks** window transparent:

```
DWORD MakeWindowTransparent(HWND hWnd, unsigned char factor)
{
    /* First, see if we can get the API call we need. If we've tried
     * once, we don't need to try again. */
    if (!initialized)
    {
        HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"user32");

        pSetLayeredWindowAttributes =
            (PSLWA)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SetLayeredWindowAttributes");

        initialized = TRUE;
    }

    if (pSetLayeredWindowAttributes == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    /* Windows need to be layered to be made transparent. This is done
     * by modifying the extended style bits to contain WS_EX_LAYARED. */
    SetLastError(0);

    auto winlong = SetWindowLong(hWnd,
    GWL_EXSTYLE,
    GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

    if ((winlong == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0)) { 
        auto error = GetLastErrorAsString(); 
        return FALSE;
    } 

    if (!pSetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(255, 255, 255),factor, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA))
    { 
        auto error = GetLastErrorAsString(); 
        return FALSE; 
    } 

    return TRUE;
}


int main() {
  HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, L"BlueStacks");
  MakeWindowTransparent(hWnd, 0);
}
```

BlueStacks can run in `opengl` and `directx`, I have tested the code above, using both modes.

`MakeWindowTransparent` is returning 0

`pSetLayeredWindowAttributes` `auto error = GetLastErrorAsString();` error returned is: `wrong parameter`.

I have tested the code with other OpenGL windows, and it did not pause in any of the errors, also the window got transparent correctly.

Some information I have collected about the window:

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `MakeWindowTransparent` returning?
As per docs, call `GetLastError` to see what the system might be telling you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy `return pSetLayeredWindowAttributes` returns 0

Comment: Where is the actual failure?  `MakeWindowTransparent()` returns false under 3 different conditions - 1) if `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is not available in `user32.dll`; 2) if `SetWindowLong()` fails; 3) if `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` fails. So, which failure is actually happening?  And what does `GetLastError()` actually return when that failure occurs? Also FYI, calling `GetLastError()` after `SetWindowLong()` is only valid if `SetWindowLong()` returns 0, which you are not checking for. If `SetWindowLong()` returns non-zero, the value of `GetLastError()` is *indeterminate*

Comment: @RemyLebeau GetLastError() are not being triggered `pSetLayeredWindowAttributes` = (user32.dll!0x00007ffff3a33170) `SetWindowLong` returns (262144)

Comment: @Caio that is not what I asked.  WHICH of the API functions is failing exactly - `LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()`, `SetWindowLong()`, or `SetLayeredWindowAttribute()`?  And what does `GetLastError()` return exactly for THAT specific failed function? You are checking `GetLastError()` in only 1 of the 4 possible failure points of this code. You need to write better error handling logic if you want to discover the root cause of the failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry i'm still learning, does this help? https://imgur.com/a/P0Gc4Kl
`winlong = SetWindowLong()` and `mwt = makewindowtransparent()`

Comment: @Caio That shows `SetWindowLong()` returning non-zero, which means the subsequent `GetLastError()` needs to be skipped. We can't see whether or not `GetLastError()` after `SetWindowLong()` is returning non-zero, making `MakeWindowTransparent()` exit prematurely before it is able to call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`. DO NOT check `GetLastError()` after `SetWindowLong()` UNLESS AND ONLY IF `SetWindowLong()` returns 0, eg: `LONG winlong = SetWindowLong(...); if ((winlong == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0)) return FALSE;` That will then allow `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` to be called *properly*.

Comment: @Caio If, after that point, you find `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` is actually being called, and it is returning 0, then you need to check `GetLastError()` again to find out WHY it is returning 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I confirmed the window is not getting WS_EX_LAYERED any idea what else I could try?

Comment: @Caio confirmed HOW exactly?

Comment: I have download AutoHotkey and did a loop: `WinSet,ExStyle,+0x02000000,BlueStacks` and checked the window properties using Winspector, on StylesEx it did not get `WS_EX_LAYERED`, I also tested the loop in other windows and it did got the parameter correctly. I too checked the window properties just right after `SetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using both flags `LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA`? If you are specifying a color `RGB(255, 255, 255)`, just use `LWA_COLORKEY`.

Also, why are you messing with `GetProcAddress`? `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is available starting with Windows 2000; are you targeting platforms older than that?

I am not familiar with **BlueStacks**, but [SetLayeredWindowAttributes to make a window transparent is only working part of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383681/setlayeredwindowattributes-to-make-a-window-transparent-is-only-working-part-of) suggests that `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` doesn't work with `Direct3D`; do you know if **BlueStacks** uses `Direct3D`?

For `OpenGL` see this: [How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background)

**UPDATE**
I was playing with that **BlueStacks**, and figured that you can re-parent it to another window (that's not recommended, as you will need to handle some edge cases). Anyway, I used an existing `Notepad` window and was able to set alpha on it, and that affected the child **BlueStacks** window:

```
int main() {
  HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"BlueStacks");
  HWND hWndN = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
  ::SetParent(hWnd, hWndN);

  auto winlong1 = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
  auto winlong2 = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE);
  ::SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

  MakeWindowTransparent(hWndN, 200);
}
```

I've also cleaned up your function to get rid of `GetProcAddress`:

```
DWORD MakeWindowTransparent(HWND hWnd, unsigned char factor)
{
  auto winlong = SetWindowLong(hWnd,
    GWL_EXSTYLE,
    GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

  if ((winlong == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, factor, LWA_ALPHA))
  {
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Windows10, about the colors in calling the function `MakeWindowTransparent(hWnd, 0);` Im currently using opengl @Vlad Feinstein

Comment: i tried to follow this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055059/12733526 but my code did not compiles after I add it. I have add #include <dwmapi.h> and the code, and got this error when compiling: `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow referenced in function "private: enum ResultType __cdecl Line::Launcher(wchar_t *,wchar_t *,bool)"`

Comment: I have updated the topic with new information, also the error returned by `GetLastError()`

Comment: @Caio (1) could you please remove `LWA_ALPHA` and just pass `LWA_COLORKEY`? (2) Could you please make sure that `hWnd` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Vlad, thank you for your time, (1) I have removed `LWA_ALPHA` and pass only `LWA_COLORKEY` but it still did not get transparent, (2) I confirmed the handle is not NULL also collect some information about the window, I hope this can help: https://imgur.com/a/o3K313M

Comment: @Caio - Re: `but it still did not get transparent` - but did it fail? I still think you have to follow up on `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`. Did you link `Dwmapi.lib`?

Comment: It did failed on `!pSetLayeredWindowAttributes` im gonna try again, i did not had linked `Dwmapi.lib`, Edit: with the included lib it compiled, `auto dwm = DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &bb)` dwm returned `S_OK`, but window still visible: https://imgur.com/a/YjftlsF

Comment: So, the mystery is partially solved: you get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because the window is still not `WS_EX_LAYERED`. That's another problem - a call to `SetWindowLong` didn't fail, but it didn't set that style either. For the `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`, it appears that you need to do something in the OpenGL app (see that link in my answer).

Comment: I confirmed the window is not getting `WS_EX_LAYERED` any idea what else I could try?

Comment: Vlad, Wow so amazing!! Can't thank you enough :) I'm testing the code right now, and return to give a feedback

Comment: Vlad, using SetParent when i try to capture the BlueStack window using `GdipBitmapFromHandle` the bitmap captured is all black, happens the same if I try to capture the re-parent window, here: https://youtu.be/HVrUyvbQqck (black screenshot is an attempt to capture Bluestack hwnd, white screenshot re-parent window)

Comment: @Caio - sorry, I don't know how to capture that thing. As this is a different issue, I suggest you post a new question about that.